# Add a hidden value for each row in Handson table

Tags: javascript, handsontable

[image]

How Can add a hidden value for each row, like a unique row id (generated from the database) and then get that value when saving the data ? I will be using this value for deciding whether that particular row needs to be inserted or updated in database while saving the data.

I can hide the column while pre-populating, but when i am trying to get the data it is not available.

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 0):

[Array data source with hidden columns](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.23.0/tutorial-data-sources.html#page-array-hidden). Note that the `Kia` column will be hidden.

```
 var hiddenData = [
  ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Mazda', 'Ford'],
  ['2012', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
  ['2013', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
  ['2014', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
  ['2015', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
  ['2016', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
],
container = document.getElementById('example2'),
hot2;

 hot2 = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: hiddenData,
   colHeaders: true,
   minSpareRows: 1,
   columns: [
     {data: 0},
     {data: 2},
     {data: 3},
     {data: 4},
     {data: 5},
     {data: 6}
   ]
 });
```

Use `hot2.getData()` to get all data including the data of the hidden column.

I have prepared a JSfiddle for you. Have a look. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsk90/19hL2nrj/)

Comment: Thanks for the your reply. I have gone through the documentation and yes i can hide the data with the approach you have mentioned but then the thing is the values of the hidden column are not available when i am trying to save the data, i only get the data that is visible in the table.

Comment: Use `hot2.getData()`. What do you get?

Comment: I got the issue, if i use the latest version of handson table i.e "0.23.0", it doesn't works, you can try the same link which u have mentioned in the start of your answer, if i try with the js which u have used in your jsfiddle it somehow works.